# Invalid callback: Model on custom cron module

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I am trying to make a custom module to run a **cron job** to assign products to categories.

I am however missing something, and I keep getting errors, and the **cron job** shows up, but doesn't work.

**/public_html/app/code/local/Firmname/Catcron/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Firmname_Catcron>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Firmname_Catcron>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <firmname_catcron>
                <class>Firmname_Catcron_Model</class>
            </firmname_catcron>                         
        </models>
    </global>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <firmname_catcron>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>Firmname_catcron/observer::crontask</model></run>
            </firmname_catcron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**/public_html/app/code/local/Firmname/Catcron/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Firmname_Catcron_Model_Observer {
  public function crontask() {
        // code
    }
}
```

**/public_html/app/etc/modules/Firmname_Catcron.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Firmname_Catcron>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Firmname_Catcron>
  </modules>
</config>
```

The error:

> ---EXCEPTION--- Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid callback: Model for Firmname_catcron/observer::crontask does not exist in
> /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/Mage.php:598 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Helper/Data.php(298):
>
> Mage::throwException('Invalid callbac...')
>
> ## 1 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Job.php(143):
>
> Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_Data->getCallBack('Firmname_catcron/...')
>
> ## 2 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(192):
>
> Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Job->getCallback()
>
> ## 3 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(582):
>
> Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
>
> ## 4 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39):
>
> Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
>
> ## 5 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358):
>
> Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> ## 6 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337):
>
> Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer),
> 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> ## 7 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(451): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
>
> ## 8 /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/cron.php(83): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
>
> ## 9 {main}

I really hope someone has an idea as to why I am struggling so much to get my module to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alias for model is `firmname_catcron` and you call the cron with

```
<run><model>Firmname_catcron/observer::crontask</model></run>
```

I guess the uppercase **F** of `Firmname` instead of `firmname` could be the source of your issue.

Please, try with :

```
<run><model>firmname_catcron/observer::crontask</model></run>
```

Comment: That was the solution in my case! I can't believe i missed that one.
Many thanks for your help!